# C# - Unexpected character encountered while parsing value

Tags: c#, json

Here is my code:

```
private void OnIncomingData(string data)
{
    Console.WriteLine("RECEIVED: "  + data);
    TransferData transfer = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TransferData>(data);
}
```

I receive an error:

> JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing
>   value: {. Path 'data', line 1, position 26.

Here is what my `Console.WriteLine` gives:

> RECEIVED:
>   {"header":"0x001","data":{"connectionId":"85"},"connectionId":85}

Here is my `TransferData` class:

```
public class TransferData
{
    public string header;
    public string data;
    public int connectionId;
}
```

As you can see the json string is correct. Why than I receive this error? How can I fix it?

Comment: `data` in the json doesn't look rights. It's not a string, it's a object with a `connectionId` property.

Answer (score 1):

Your type says that `Data` is a string, but it looks like an object to me. Think you need something like:

```
public class TransferData
{
    public string header;
    public Data data;
    public int connectionId;
}

public class Data
{
    public int connectionId;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your model does not correspond to JSON schema as in JSON you have an object `data` while in model it's string. Either wrap the object in JSON is string, or change `data` type either to type describing what you can receive, or to `JObject`

Comment: How can I wrap it with is string? What do you mean. Can you give example ?

Comment: change `"data":{"connectionId":"85"}` to `"data": "{\"connectionId\":\"85\"}"`. Is this really what you need? You'll end with JSON string in data field of your model